# How to use Django signals when has role based decorators?

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

Update, I have created a signal file like this, so for example if an employer has created a shift, the admin will get an email notification like this:

```
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver
from .models import Shift

from django.core.mail import send_mail


@receiver(post_save, sender=Shift)
def send_mail_to_user(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        send_mail(
                'A new shift has been created by employer xxx',
                'Here is the message.',
                'from@example.com',
                ['to@example.com'],
                fail_silently=False,
            )
```

Original post:

Hi, I 'm trying to add signals when an employer or admin/staff has created a shift. Currently I have a view like this, I 'm wondering how should I modify it so I can have a post-save signal?

```
@login_required
@admin_staff_employer_required

def createShift(request):
    user=request.user
    employer=Employer.objects.all()
    
    form = CreateShiftForm()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = CreateShiftForm(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():

            form.save()
            messages.success(request, "The shift has been created")

            return redirect('/shifts')
        else:
            messages.error(request,"Please correct your input field and try again")

    context = {'form':form}

    return render(request, 'create_shift.html', context)
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this(in this case I suppose your app name is 'almo' and model name is 'Shift').

signals.py

```py
from .models import Shift
from django.dispatch import receiver
from django.db.models.signals import post_save

@receiver(post_save, sender=Shift)
def shift_created_callback(sender, **kwargs):
    print('shift created!')
    # do something

# arguments can be added by your taste
# def shift_created_callback(sender, instance, **kwargs):
# def shift_created_callback(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
```

apps.py

```py
from django.apps import AppConfig

class AlmoConfig(AppConfig):
    default_auto_field = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'
    name = 'almo'

    def ready(self):
        import almo.signals
```

You can see 'shift created' in console when you create shift

Comment: Tks @oh_yucheol,  it did show. What I have concerned was when had role based views, in my case, admin_only, admin_and_employer only...,so it does not matter to keep those permissions when creating signals file right? I have not seen or may have not noticed any tutorials that have both user permission views and corresponding signals. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Signals and permissions are seperated feature, so there are no interference between two, I think. Once Shift instance saved in database, signal should be generated. User's permission can't affect this process. In your case only permitted user(admin, staff, employer) can create Shift instance, that means other user(e.g. employees) can't generate signal. Hope this helps.

Comment: Perfect explanation. Thank you :D

Answer (score 1):

You have to create a new function that will be the receiver of the post-save signal. It is explained here in the docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/signals/#connecting-to-signals-sent-by-specific-senders

Basically, you would need to set the sender to your model class, and on every post_save signal the handler function would get triggered. If you need a specific signal you can create your custom ones: https://thetldr.tech/how-to-add-custom-signals-dispatch-in-django/ , but for your use case you can trigger the function on every save of the shift model.

```
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver
#here you have to import your Shift model


@receiver(post_save, sender=Shift)
def my_handler(sender, **kwargs):
    print('Shift created')
```

Also import the signals file in your apps.py file like so:

```
from django.apps import AppConfig


class ApplicationConfig(AppConfig):
    name = "<your app name>"

    def ready(self):
        from <app_name> import <signal_recievers_file_name>
```

This should print "Shift created" to your console once you create a new shift.

Comment: Hi @Bratix thanks for your reply. I have read that Django document but still not sure how should I implement it. I tried to created a signal file. Am I in a right direction?

Comment: Yes I think creating the file to store handler functions of signals is a good first step. After that just create a function like in the Django docs and set the sender to your Shift model class. For testing you can put a print statement in the handler function just to see if it works and try creating a shift and then see if the print statement is displayed in the console. I will also edit my answer to provide the handler function,

Comment: Thanks @Bratix for your help! I was trying to figure out how to have both role_based  views and signals working together. Your answer inspired me. :) Thank you!